# Weblogic work manager

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am new to weblogic server. I am using work manager. I want to know what is work manager and why we need it. What is the difference between normal request with out work manager and with work manager !!

Answer (score 6):

I think [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html) is rather good on this subject.

> WebLogic Server prioritizes work and allocates threads based on an
>   execution model that takes into
>   account administrator-defined
>   parameters and actual run-time
>   performance and throughput.
>
> Administrators can configure a set of
>   scheduling guidelines and associate
>   them with one or more applications, or
>   with particular application
>   components. For example, you can
>   associate one set of scheduling
>   guidelines for one application, and
>   another set of guidelines for other
>   application. At run-time, WebLogic
>   Server uses these guidelines to assign
>   pending work and enqueued requests to
>   execution threads.

Essentially, with work managers you can attach a scheduling policy to an application to e.g. make sure that a specific application gets a fair share of the available computing resources under a heavy load situation. Or you might want to restict the maximum number of threads that will be allocated to an application to prevent a buggy/untested application to bring the whole application server to its knees. (But surely all apps have been tested not to do anything like that.... ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Outside of modifying the default allocation algorithms, the Work Manager is also useful if you are using a Foreign JMS Provider (such as IBM MQ) and need to process more than 16 messages at a time.